# ReSharper confused my visual studio - reset visual studio with defaults

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

I used ReSharper in order to do some tasks and after uninstalled it because it confused me (all the highlights ad the quick links.. I prefer the default behaveior of visual studio).

After I uninstalled it - compilation errors that used to be underlined with red line now has no underline at all.

How can I reset visual studio with the defauld behaveior?

Comment: What, you don't like an IDE littered with neon signs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Tools > Import/Export Settings > Reset All Settings`

Answer (score 0):

The ReSharper team has accounted for this use case for the last few versions (Wanting to run VS without R#) So for next time there's an easier way: Tools > Options > ReSharper > Suspend

Info From the dialog:

> Suspends ReSharper.
>
> All of the ReSharper actions will be unavailable, the background
>   analyses will not be running, the memory will be freed, and CPU
>   consumption will cease.
>
> This action is also available with Visual Studio commands
>   ReSharper_Suspend and ReSharper_ToggleSuspended.
>
> To restore ReSharper functionality, you will have to resume it
>   manually in this dialog or with ReSharper_Resume

The ReSharper Options are on the same property dialog and you can turn off the stuff that annoys you.

Comment: I saw that and did that before uninstall but it doesn't help. Red underlines were gone.

Comment: does the restore the vs hotkeys?